Изменилась ли ситуация с переводом через 9 лет
Я знаю, что команда Stack Exchange 6 лет назад сказала что пока что не будут переводить другие сайты сети на другие языки, кроме английского (почитать об этом можно здесь
https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20988/internationalization-state-of-the-stack)
Изменилась ли ситуация спустя 9 лет? Будет ли команда Stack Exchange переводить другие сайты на другие языки?
Я думаю, что сейчас стоит опять поднять такие вопросы, как этот:
Почему нету сообщества "математика на русском" и другие переводы сайтов сети.

В моём понимании ситуация никак не изменилась. А скорее даже укрепилась в том, что новых неанглоязычных сайтов создавать не стоит.
Хотя технологии машинного перевода и продвинулись существенно с тех пор, всё равно между разными языками и культурами будет большая пропасть. Как между обычными пользователями, так и между модераторами. Неанглоязычные сайты будут считаться второстепенными, несмотря на количество сообщений/посещений/пользователей. Чтобы как-то продвинуться в этом направлении надо открывать филиалы в странах с этими языками или хотя бы иметь в штате определенное количество сотрудников, владеющих помимо английского дополнительно нужным языком и задействованных в развитии соответствующего сайта.
Имеющиеся сайты едут по инерции и остаются нишевыми. Проблемы таких сайтов всегда решаются медленнее, чем англоязычных сайтов. А функционал англоязычного StackOverflow существенно шире, не говоря уже о количестве информации и скорости получения ответов.
Достаточно ли прошло времени и подходящий ли сейчас момент, чтобы пересмотреть решение о появлении новых неанглоязычных сайтов, надо узнавать явно не на ruSO.meta, а на MSE или даже той самой Area51.
